# Lua - including file doesnt work, how can I fix it?

Tags: lua

I have a problem with lua include (dofile, loadfile, require). What I want to do is including file to my main lua file.

- Main file - stala_2enb_lua.lua
- File to include - zmienne_2enb_modyfikacja

I want to have my main file constant and make changes only in second file, where I want to have variables.

Main file

[image: Main file]

---

File to include

[image: File to include]

I tried all ways like on the screen, but I have no output. It behaves like this all including doesnt matter. There is no error and the variables are not included. How can I make it correctly?

**UPDATE**

I've managed to load a little bit using dofile, but there is an error which I can't understand.  I've found a solution, but i can't understand it properly --> devdocs.io/nginx_lua_module --> ctrf +f = Lua Coroutine Yielding/Resuming

Error after loading function using dofile ("/home/epcsim/WTS_2001_WK05/zmienne_2enb_lua.lua")

[image: Error]

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: what does your second file look like?

Comment: Thank you for the response - I've added the second file to the link above. The file is much longer, but there isnt new constructions - only exec.

Comment: `dofile` line should work

Comment: Unfortunately, dofile "name", "name.lua" "fullpath/name" " fullpath/name.lua" doesnt work just like loadfile and require.

Comment: What environment is this being done in? is it a nodemcu? or just a command line

Comment: It's my company internal software - LTE EPC Emulator. Ok, I've managed to load a little bit using dofile, but there is an error. I will attach a screen above. I've found a solution on this error, but i can't understand it properly --> devdocs.io/nginx_lua_module --> ctrf +f = Lua Coroutine Yielding/Resuming